# lex/yacc how do i access memory using an array?

Tags: memory-management, yacc, lex, memory-access

Im been trying to create a compiler using yacc/lex, but i can't seem to find how to make a direct access to the memory, similar to c++ like Array[2].

I have found some using strings, but im having dificults trying to generalize it for other types of data.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to parse an expression of the form `array[index]` or how to translate it to a memory access? For the former, depending on your language's exact syntax, that'd be something like `expression '[' expression ']'` accompanied by the appropriate precedence annotations. If you tried this and it didn't work, please post a [MCVE] including a description of the expected vs. actual behavior. In the latter case, it depends on the structure of your compiler, your language's semantics etc.

Comment: Regarding "I have found some using strings", I'm really not sure what you mean there. It would help if you specified what exactly you found and what difficulties you encountered trying to generalize it.